# Ignoring diacritics when searching in Ant Design Select Component with OptGroups

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using [Select component](https://ant.design/components/select/) from Ant Design. 
I'd like to use option groups with search.

**Requirements:**

1. Options are grouped to OptGroups
2. Search works on Options (not OptGroups)
3. Option values are numbers (IDs from database), not text
4. Search is not sensitive to accent marks (i.e. when I type `ca`, the option `čaj` should be offered)

The **first three requirements work out-of-the-box**:

```
  <Select 
    showSearch
    defaultValue="2"
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    optionFilterProp="children"
  >
    <OptGroup label="Manager">
      <Option value="1">Jack</Option>
      <Option value="2">Lucy</Option>
    </OptGroup>
    <OptGroup label="Engineer">
      <Option value="3">yiminghe</Option>
    </OptGroup>
  </Select>
```

Troubles begin with the fourth requirement. It seems like I need to provide my own filter. Luckily, AntDesign has a property for that, it's called `filterOption`. Let's try it:

```
  <Select 
    showSearch
    defaultValue="2"
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    filterOption={(input, option) => 
        prepareStrForSearch(option.props.children).includes(prepareStrForSearch(input))
    }
  >
    <OptGroup label="Manager">
      <Option value="1">Jack</Option>
      <Option value="2">Lucy</Option>
    </OptGroup>
    <OptGroup label="Engineer">
      <Option value="3">yiminghe</Option>
    </OptGroup>
  </Select>
```

The page renders, let's try search. Yikes. The browser screams:

[image: Cannot read property includes of undefined.]

Apparently, `filterOption` receives `OptGroup` for filtering, instead of `Option`. However, **I need to search in Options, not OptGroups. What is the easiest way to implement this?**

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to `return false` for OptGroups. (Seems counter-intuitive to me.) Afterwards, Ant Design will call the `filterOption` function again with the `Option`s.

Here's an example:

```
  <Select 
    showSearch
    defaultValue="2"
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    filterOption={(input, option) => {
      if (option.props.value) {
          return strForSearch(option.props.children).includes(
              strForSearch(input)
          );
      } else {
          return false;
      }
    }}>
    <OptGroup label="Manager">
      <Option value="1">Jack</Option>
      <Option value="2">Lucy</Option>
      <Option value="3">Čaj</Option>
    </OptGroup>
    <OptGroup label="Engineer">
      <Option value="3">yiminghe</Option>
    </OptGroup>
  </Select>
```

And my function to remove diacritics:

```
const strForSearch = str => {
  return str
    ? str
        .normalize("NFD")
        .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
        .toLowerCase()
    : str;
};
```